# D'aucuns vs. aucun

Tags: vocabulaire, pronoms, négation, étymologie

How comes does *[d'aucuns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%27aucuns)* mean some while *[aucun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aucun)* means none?

Example:

> 1. Comme d’aucuns le disent, ...: As some people say, ...
> 2. Aucun Anglais ne demanderait ça: No Englishman would ask this

Comment: D'aucuns est une ancienne forme pour quelques. C'est dommage qu'elle reste figée dans des expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

« Aucun » signifiait à l'origine « quelqu'un », du latin *aliquis unus* -> *alicunus* qui a aussi donné *alcuni* en italien et *alguno* en espagnol.

Comme quelques autres mots employés dans des tournures négatives (pas, point, personne, rien, plus, jamais, ...), il a fini par signifier **aussi** son contraire, suivant le contexte.

- « Il n'avance **pas** » -> *he doesn't walk a **step***.
- « Il avance **pas** à **pas**» -> *he walks **step** by **step***.
- « Je ne vois **personne** » -> *I don't see **anybody***.
- « Je vois une **personne** » -> *I see **somebody***.
- « Ce n'est **rien** » -> *This is not **anything***. (*This is nothing*)
- « Ce sont des petits **riens** » -> *These are small **things***.
- « Je n'en veux **plus** » -> *I don't want any **more** of it*.
- « J'en veux **plus** » -> *I want **more** of it*.
- « Il ne reviendra **jamais** » -> *He won't **ever** come back*.
- « Si **jamais** il reviens » -> *If he **ever** come back*.

Sous la forme « d'aucuns », il a conservé son sens original.

Comment: "pas" du latin "passus".

Answer (score 0):

On pourrait remplacer dans vos phrases :

> - *d'aucuns* par certains, plusieurs,
>   *d'aucuns* est une expression qui met au pluriel *aucun de* (pronom avec une valeur positive) signifie *quiconque parmi* ou *l'un de*.
> - *aucun* (pronom avec une valeur négative) par *nul*, *pas un* (ou *personne* si l'on supprime le mot Anglais).

source : Le Robert

Comment: Thanks, I was actually wondering why adding "d'" inverses the meaning of aucun.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt j'ai ajouté une précision sur l'origine de *aucun de*. *Aucun* peut prendre un valeur positive ou négative : le *d'* ou *de* peut être rattaché à l'une ou à l'autre.