# « Personne ne va rien faire » : double négation ?

Tags: pronoms, négation, double-négation

Le mot « personne » est négatif par lui-même, par exemple :

> Il n'y a personne ici

On n'a pas besoin de dire :

> Il n'y a pas de personne ici

C'est vrai aussi pour le mot "rien"

> Je ne vais rien faire (**pas** je ne vais pas faire rien)

Donc je me demande si « *Nobody is going to do anything* » en français se dit :

> Personne ne va rien faire

**Personne** est négatif aussi bien que **rien** et **ne**, donc est-ce que je dois utiliser ces trois mots ensemble ?

Comment: "Il n'y a pas de personne ici" : dans cette phrase *personne* est un simple nom commun et ne fait pas partie de la négation, tu peux mette *chat* à la place : "Il n'y a pas de chat ici". Par ailleurs je ne comprends pas comment tu es passé de "*I'm not going...*" à "Personne ne va..." j'aurais dit "je en vais..." Peut-être une faute de frappe, je n'ai pas corrigé car je ne suis pas sûr et ne veux pas changer le sens de ce que tu veux dire.

Comment: A noter anecdotiquement : au Québec il me semble que l'usage du terme est différent, et on entend des phrases comme *Il n'y a **pas** personne*, ou *Y'a **pas** personne ?*, là où le français de la métropole omettrait le terme *pas*. A confirmer éventuellement par un *vrai* québecois ;-)

Comment: Je suis désolé -  c'est nobody -  j'ai déjà réparé la phrase.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Non, au Québec on dit "*Y'a personne (icitte)?*". La phrase "*Y'a **pas** personne.*" signifierait "*Il y a du monde*", quoique incorrecte grammaticalement. La double négation est, malgré tout, souvent utilisée au Québec comme dans "*T'es pas laide*", mais c'est un tout autre sujet de discution.

Comment: @Sifu merci de ton avis éclairé. Je tenais mon exemple d'un ami français ayant vécu à Trois-Rivières pendant quelques années pour le boulot. Ca faisait partie des idiolectes qui l'avaient surpris et dont il m'avait parlé. Il doit y avoir eu une confusion quelque part... merci pour la rectification !

Comment: Au vu des réponses, je vois mieux pourquoi on me regarde souvent bizarrement quand je demande, par exemple, « As-tu jamais [...] ? »... Parfois même on me « corrige » en me signifiant que je devrais dire « N'as-tu jamais [...] ? ».

Comment: P.S. car je ne peux plus éditer : les deux phrases ci-dessus sont correctes mais n'ont pas tout à fait le même sens. *As-tu jamais* se traduit en anglais par *Have you ever* (en langage courant on dirait plutôt *As-tu déjà*), alors que *N'as-tu jamais* se traduit par *Have you never*. En général, les termes comme *jamais*, *rien*, *aucun*, *personne*, etc. employés seuls se traduisent par *ever*, *anything*, *any*, *anybody*, etc. C'est l'adjonction de *ne* qui leur donne le sens de *never*, *nothing*, *none*, *nobody*, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Étymologiquement, c'est le mot *ne* qui indique la négation en français. Des mots comme *rien*, *personne*, *jamais*, etc. qualifient la négation (*rien* indique qu'on nie l'existence d'une chose, *personne* l'existence d'une personne, *jamais* l'existence d'un moment, etc.) mais ne sont pas en eux-même négatifs.

En français moderne, on ne peut pas utiliser *ne* tout seul. Les constructions comme *ne … pas*, *ne … personne*, *ne … rien*, etc. sont vues comme des négations en deux parties. Si l'on nie plusieurs aspects en même temps, le mot *ne* peut être combiné avec plusieurs adverbes :

> Il n'y a personne ici.
>   Personne ne va rien faire. (qui signifie « *nobody will do anything* », pas « *I will not do anything* »)
>   Personne ne fait plus jamais rien nulle part. (*Nobody ever does anything anywhere anymore.*)

En français moderne familier, à l'oral, on omet souvent le mot *ne*. C'est une évolution assez logique : puisque les mots *pas*, *personne*, *rien*, *jamais*, *nulle part*, *aucun*, etc. sont déjà perçus comme indiquant une négation, la particule *ne* est redondante. Même si chaque adverbe indique une négation, si on les compose, on a toujours une phrase négative : deux négations ne font pas une phrase positive.

> [oral] Y'a personne ici.
>   [oral] Personne va rien faire.
>   [oral] Personne fait pus jamais rien nulle part.

Comment: Quelques exemples complémentaires ici: http://french.stackexchange.com/a/7452/79

Answer (score 4):

C'est ridicule de dire que *rien* et *personne* ne sont pas des termes négatifs! Ici, *rien* est un élément crucial de l'adverbe de négation composé *ne+pas/rien/personne...*. En français, la négation normale (si on la compare à l'anglais) est en effet une double négation, mais on considère généralement que ne et son "auxiliaire" (j'emprunte le terme au *Bon Usage* de Grevisse) forme une seule et même entité (au même titre que des conjonctions comme *avant que*)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item). Un parallèle seraient probablement les circumpositions, comme ***à*** un détail **près**.

Quand à *personne*, s'il s'agit ici non d'un terme de négation à proprement parler, mais d'un pronom normal. Toutefois, ce pronom est un [**terme à polarité négative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item), et au même titre que *at all* en anglais, il ne peut pas ou à peu près pas s'employer dans une phrase affirmative.

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) La négation composée prend plutôt une forme du genre *J'ai pas vu personne*. Dans ces phrases, on ne prononce à peu près jamais *ne*, car elles appartiennent à un registre familier, dans lequel c'est l'auxiliaire qui fait office d'unique adverbe de négation, comme en anglais.

Answer (score 0):

« Rien » signifie étymologiquement « *rem* », c'est à dire « chose », c'est en association avec « ne  », donc « ne ... rien », qu'il forme une négation.

« Personne » est lui aussi ambivalent (voir [D'aucuns vs. aucun](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/daucuns-vs-aucun/9591#9591) ). « Personne ne vient » contient une seule négation et se traduit par « *Nobody comes* » et pas par « *Nobody does not come* ».

« Personne ne va rien faire » signifie donc « (Aucune) personne ne fera quelque chose / Personne ne fera quoi que ce soit ».

« *I'm not going to do anything* » peut se traduire « Je ne vais rien faire du tout ».