# « Pas » peut-il être utilisé pour exagerer une expression en général ou juste dans ce cas?

Tags: négation, emphase

J'ai lu dans *L'Étranger* en parlant d'un homme qui maltraite son chien

> «Si c'est pas malheureux!»

Est-ce un dicton seulement ou peut-on utiliser « pas » pour souligner n'importe quoi comme par ironie ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plusieurs interprétations semblent a priori plausibles, mais au final, aucune ne m’a encore convaincu, et je demeure dubitatif face à cette excellente question. Si je devais donner mon opinion, ma préférence irait sans doute au tabou *(décrit ci-dessous)*, mais je demeure conscient des défauts de l’explication.

#### Omission de la particule négative ?

On pourrait par exemple présumer que la particule négative « ne » serait simplement omise à cause de l’usage familier de l’expression. Quelques mécanismes peuvent être invoqués pour justifier la valeur positive de *malheureux* :

> - Si ce n’est pas malheureux, *je ne sais pas ce que c’est!*
> - Est-ce que ce n’est pas malheureux! *[Cette question qui n’en est pas une peut même avoir une forte valeur positive quand le ton est approprié.]*

Pour le premier cas, on remarquera cependant que l’usage habituel ne laisse pas présumer d’une phrase qui serait à compléter par le destinataire : elle se termine abruptement, comme s’il n’y avait rien à ajouter.

Pour le deuxième cas, on notera que le *si* de l’expression originale est disparu sans laisser d’adresse. On ne saurait plus le replacer avec la tournure qu’a prise la phrase, et on ne saurait par conséquent expliquer sa présence.

Une autre option, peut-être plus facile à défendre, sera de dire que l’affirmation est ironique, qu’on nie le caractère malheureux de la situation pour mieux le faire sentir. Un exemple sans négation, mais déclarant clairement le contraire de ce qui est affirmé, serait *« C’est du joli! »*. Avec un mot négatif, on pourrait penser à *« Il (n’)y a rien là! »* quand la tâche désignée semble de toute évidence relever du quasi-impossible.

Mon expérience personnelle ne m’a cependant pas indiqué d’ironie dans la grande majorité des utilisations de *« Si c’est pas malheureux »*, mais plutôt de la compassion. Je demeure sceptique.

Par contre, étant donné ce caractère habituellement empathique de l’expression, on pourrait penser à une espèce de tabou ou de réserve sur le caractère malheureux de la situation : ne pas la décrire dans toute l’ampleur de sa portée afin de lui laisser le maximum de chance de s’améliorer.

#### *Pas* a valeur positive¹ ?

*Le bon usage*, sauf erreur de ma part, demeure curieusement silencieux à propos de cette expression en particulier. Il traite par contre brièvement de certains cas d’emplois positifs de mots négatifs², notant toutefois que « le contexte est presque toujours négatif ou dubitatif », et aussi que cet usage apparaît le plus souvent dans « la langue soignée ». Malheureusement, *pas* et *point* n’y sont mentionnés que pour le premier de cinq cas possibles, soit pour l’emploi en des phrases interrogatives : *« Viens-tu PAS demander asile ?» (Victor Hugo, Hernani)*. Le cas qui nous occupe n’est pas une question, mais une affirmation claire, et on ne saurait trouver ici plus qu’une ébauche d’hypothèse.

Du côté des dictionnaires, on observera qu’à l’article *malheureux*, [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/malheureux/48893/locution?q=malheureux#173661) autant que Le Petit Robert ne mentionnent que la forme proposée dans la question. Bien que les deux décrivent l’expression comme familière et s’abstiennent d’offrir une étymologie au lecteur curieux, on pourra trouver étrange qu’il n’y ait pas au moins mention d’une forme incluant le *ne*, si cette forme avait une existence historique. Sans conclure, on peut ajouter la pièce au dossier.

Si l’on regarde maintenant vers l’usage habituel, on remarquera des variantes du type :

> - C’est-y pas malheureux. *[Nous avons de nouveau la suppression du* si *et la forme pseudo-interrogative, via la particule* -y³, *critiquée et appartenant à la langue populaire, mais bien vivante dans certaines régions.]*
> - Si c’est pas un rien malheureux. *[Ici, présence de* rien, *un autre mot habituellement négatif, mais à valeur clairement positive, ainsi qu’on le déduira de la présence de l’article* un *avant.]*
> - *[Souvent entendu au Québec, je ne sais pas pour ailleurs :]* Si c’est pas malheureux, rien qu’un peu!

...aux côtés, cependant, d’autres où la négation est réintroduite, à l’instar de la première hypothèse ci-dessus, avec les mêmes remarques que ci-dessus :

> - Ça n’est-ti pas malheureux.
> - Si ce n’est pas malheureux (rien qu’un peu). *[Auquel cas il faudra de nouveau avoir recours à un subterfuge pour expliquer la valeur positive.]*

Toutes ces variantes souffrent du fait qu’elles sont familières, donc peu soumises aux normes sévères de la grammaire et de l’usage historique, et qu’une interprétation personnelle, pour peu qu’elle soit perçue plausible, suffira parfois à entériner une certaine forme qui eût peut-être été considérée comme absurde dans le passé. De nouveau, difficile de conclure.

#### Les attestations

[Une requête avec Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=si+c%27est+pas+malheureux%2Csi+ce+n%27est+pas+malheureux&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csi%20c%27est%20pas%20malheureux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BSi%20c%27est%20pas%20malheureux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsi%20c%27est%20pas%20malheureux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csi%20ce%20n%27est%20pas%20malheureux%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BSi%20ce%20n%27est%20pas%20malheureux%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsi%20ce%20n%27est%20pas%20malheureux%3B%2Cc0) nous indique que l’expression, dans sa forme avec ou sans *ne*, ne date guère que de la dernière décennie du XIXe siècle, à une époque où la particule avait déjà bien reculé dans les usages. Une recherche parmi les attestations indiquent clairement une origine populaire, et le graphique nous montre la prévalence de la forme sans *ne*. La forme l’incluant vise-t-elle donc simplement à régulariser une forme considérée fautive ? C’est possible. Au final, cependant, les dictionnaires usuels donnent malgré tout droit de cité à la forme fautive et dédaignent la forme corrigée. Serait-ce que même la correction est insuffisante pour absoudre l’expression à leurs yeux ?

[image]

---

- *¹ La valeur historique positive de bien des mots de négation est très bien attestée et n’est aucunement controversée. Elle est sommairement présentée sur ce site en quelques endroits, dont [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/20097/13100) ou [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14467/13100). Si des mots comme* **rien, aucun** *ou* **jamais** *sont aujourd’hui rarement utilisés avec leur valeur positive, on remarquera néanmoins que* **personne** *est commun autant en valeur positive (individu) que négative (absence complète d’individus).*
- *² 14e édition, §1021.*
- *³ Son statut informel confère à cette particule interrogative une grande variabilité orthographique : -ti, -t’y, -tu, ...*

Comment: Certes, cela explique toutes les hypothèses de l'utilisation. Le niveau de réponses à cette question est assez varié. Ce qui est finalement logique, c'est quand on le met dans une phrase complète "Si ce n'est pas malheureux, je ne sais pas ce que c'est!" Maintenant, cela a du sens.

Comment: J'ai eu beaucoup de difficulté à déterminer la valeur du _si_. Selon _“Si ce n'est pas malheureux, je ne sais pas ce que c'est”_, ce serait le _si_ qui marque l'hypothèse, et pourtant, de la même manière que le _pas_ ne semble guère négatif dans l'expression tronquée, le _si_ n'apparaît pas le moindrement hypothétique. Dans l'utilisation courante, il rejoint presque le _si_ marqueur d'intensité. Par exemple, communément au Québec (peut-être ailleurs aussi): “Si c'est beau!” a à peu près la même portée que “C'est si beau!”.

Comment: Moi aussi. Cela a été encore aggravé par le fait que je vis dans un pays espagnol en ce moment et que j'ai lu accidentellement si comme oui

Answer (score 3):

That particular expression is quite a fixed familiar/popular way to say :
"Est-ce que ce n'est pas malheureux", "Isn't  it a shame".

"Pas" is in no way per se an expression of irony.

Eventual irony would be reinforced though by the popular character of the sentence, generated by eliminating the "ne" in the negation "ne ... pas" (as well, generally speaking, as in the other negations "ne... rien", "ne... jamais", "ne ... personne").

As in : "J'ai jamais mangé de porc", "T'as pas vu mon pote?", "J'ai vu personne", "Il faut pas pousser".

In this last example, an even more familiar way to say would be to eliminate the impersonal subject "il": " 'Faut pas pousser" (meaning : "No need to exaggerate"), which can be ironic or not, depending on the context.

Concluding, these familiar ways of amputating the "ne" in negative forms do not necessarily contain irony, which would rather be generated by other elements of the sentence, or by the context, or by the way the sentence is said, etc.

(I) Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> ***C'est quoi***, si c'est pas malheureux !
>
> C'est quoi, si c'est pas une ***obsession*** !
>
> C'est quoi, si c'est pas + ***adjective*** / ***noun*** !

I tend to use this construction to emphasise a particular quality or thing.

Answer (score 0):

> Est-ce:
>    1) un dicton seulement ou
>    2) peut-on utilise "pas" pour
>   souligner **n'importe quoi** comme si avec ironie?

Je dirais ni l’un ni l’autre car:

> 1) il en existe au moins un autre exemple et
>     2) à part cet autre
>   exemple, je ne vois pas grande chose.

Voilà l’exemple dont je parle (Des Inconnus via *Dailymotion.com*):

[«[Avec tout ça,] On [n’]est **pas** dans la merde/le caca»](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5lna4_les-inconnus-le-bar-sketch-spectacl_fun)

pour dire le contraire, i.e., pour dire que l'on  est [vraiment] dans la merdre.