# « [...] dont d'aucuns » : contraintes de l'emploi du premier avec l'origine ou la morphologie du second, rôle ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions, pronoms-relatifs, morphologie

> La langue dispose d'outils **dont d'aucuns** ignorent souvent non
>   seulement la fonction mais aussi même jusqu'à l'existence...

C'est le pronom [*d'aucuns*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4589), *nominal indéfini de l'animé* signifiant à l'[origine](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/9591) *quelqu'un*, positivement ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aucun)), employé pour [*certains*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/daucuns/6370?q=d%27aucuns#6354), *plusieurs* ici (et [*plusieurs*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2886) signifiant souvent *beaucoup* au Québec) ; littéraire, plaisant ou soutenu, c'est selon.

L'emploi du pronom relatif [*dont*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=2904) « cache » une préposition *de* (d'où), nous dit-on, et certaines contraintes ou usages s'imposent : généralement contre-indiqué avec un antécédent précédé lui-même de la préposition *de* pour éviter le pléonasme, un déterminant possessif dans la subordonnée relative, ou un complément introduit par les prépositions *de*, *sur* ou avec le pronom *en* (BDL). Et il y a évidemment des exceptions (voir par exemple LBU14 § 722-724...).

---

- La phrase respecte-elle généralement les contraintes de l'emploi du pronom relatif
  *dont*, en aval comme en amont ; en particulier, qu'en est-il de l'antécédent, et estime-t-on que *d'aucuns* qui suit le pronom relatif contienne la préposition *de* ; la phrase est-elle syntaxiquement cohérente ; *aucuns* (pour *certains*) serait-il une alternative utile ?
- Quelle sont le ou les rôles du pronom relatif *dont* dans la phrase en question ; de
  quel(s) type(s) de complément(s) s'agit-il et complément(s) de quoi au juste ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« D'aucuns » doit être considéré ici comme une entité unique, un pronom indépendant, et non comme la préposition « de » suivie de « aucun ». Ce n'est donc pas « aucuns » qui signifie « certains » mais « d'aucuns » et il n'y a pas de contrainte de syntaxe non respectée ici.

Cette phrase peut être reformulée de façon moins littéraire comme ceci:

> La langue dispose d'outils dont **certains** ignorent souvent non seulement la fonction mais aussi même jusqu'à l'existence...

Utiliser « aucuns » seul rendrait la phrase inintelligible:

> La langue dispose d'outils dont <s>**aucuns**</s> ignorent souvent…

L'antécédent de « dont » est « outils » :

> Certains ignorent la fonction voire l'existence de ces outils.